# CSS Selector for outlook unread messages

Tags: css-selectors

What i'm trying to do is get the CSS selector for `https://outlook.live.com/mail/inbox?state=0` it is an addon for firefox which will alert how many unread messages you have, currently i have:

`div[title="Inbox"] > span:nth-child(3) > span`

This works and does not at the same time, if there is 1 unread message it shows as 11 (it adds 10 to it)

Can anyone who uses outlook see if their css selector matches up, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me if I use

```
document.querySelector(`div[title="Inbox"] > span:nth-child(3) > span span`).innerText
```

Note I added an extra span to your selector